# Is it possible to create a struct type based on file contents?

Tags: c++

Is it possible in C++ to create a struct type based on file contents?

```
STRUCT_NAME  
int var1;  
int var2;  
string v3;
STRUCT NAME *pointer;
```

The first line would be the name of the struct, the other lines would be the variables

Comment: Think you need to be a bit clearer - are you asking if it is possible to read a text file when your program runs and create a structure based on the contents of that file?

Comment: The question is, do you want to do this at run-time, or at compile-time?

Comment: Do you mean that at runtime you want to read in a text file that describes a struct and then create that struct in memory somehow?

Comment: @GrahamS, @Space_C0wb0y: I'd like to do this at run-time.

Comment: how would you refer to this "struct" in your code if you only define it at runtime? Sounds like what you want isn't actually a struct, but just a container that holds `string-int` and `string-string` key-value pairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever @lindydancer @iammilind @james are saying is correct.. You cannot do it in single go. You may get work around (Though thats not professinal way of doing) like this :
1. First read the file in which your structure is define and create new file(Cpp and h files). 
2. Now compile new file and provide new exe file to your user, you can do this process in background so that for user its all dynamic.. (But atlease someone has to do this work...)

Answer (score 2):

If you are reading from a file and trying to create this `struct`,

--> if in same program, i.e. runtime then **NO**; because you can not compile the source code which is presently executing

--> for some different source code which is yet to be compiled and you are manipulating using file operations then **YES**

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean on the fly, when your application is running? No, you can't do that, all types must be known at compile time. Of course, you can always create some kind of container object that could be configured dynamically during run-time, but that is a much more advanced system.

On the other hand, if you mean to do this once when you build you application, you could write a simple tool that eats your text file and emits a C++ header file, that you later could use when compiling.

Comment: I'd like to do this at run-time, bcuz I'd like to allow my users to define their own `struct`.

Comment: You can select from using a low-tech solution where you allocate a number of bytes that corresponds to the user structure, to a high-tech solution where you use a database to store the data. Anyway, this is a non-trivial task, and to describe it fully you really need to understand 1) the problem you are trying the handle, 2) the C++ programming language, 3) parsing techniques. Not to mention that you would have to define your own struct description language. Good luck, you will need it...

Answer (score 1):

No.  The closest you can come is an `std::map<std::string, boost::any>` (or `boost::variant` if you can limit the set of types).

Comment: The types would be only "int" and "string" and the struct would be created at run-time. Thanks for the answer